# Can I edit specflow's feature.cs file?

Tags: specflow

I am trying to create a constructor for Feature.cs file in specflow. But the behaviour is abnormal when I try to debug. Is there a way to create constructor for this feature.cs file? Or we cannot edit this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point in editing this file since it will be overwritten everytime that you modify the xxx.feature.

However the class in xxx.feature.cs is declared as partial so you can add xxx.anythingYouLike.cs to your solution with a similar partial class declaration e.g. `public partial class xxxFeature` and add whatever code you like there.

I'm not suggesting this is good practice, but it can be useful.

Comment: I am trying to create a constructor in the partial class of the feature file. But when I get a run time error saying 'unable to get default constructor for this calss'. How do I go about solving this?

Comment: SpecFlow requires the default (i.e. No args constuctor), if you are defining a constructor with Args then you also need to define the one without args.